# Pyspark : How to Map the value without join or using rdd?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe **df** looks like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, create_map
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            ("1","A","B","2020-01-01", 6), 
            ("2","A","B","2020-01-01", 6),
            ("3","A","C","2020-01-01", 6),
            ("4","A","C","2020-01-01", 6)  ,    
            ("5","B","D","2020-01-01", 10),
            ("6","B","D","2020-01-01",10),
        ],
        ["id","map1","map2","date",'var']  
    )
    +---+----+----+----------+---+
    | id|map1|map2|      date|var|
    +---+----+----+----------+---+
    |  1|   A|   B|2020-01-01|  6|
    |  2|   A|   B|2020-01-01|  6|
    |  3|   A|   C|2020-01-01|  6|
    |  4|   A|   C|2020-01-01|  6|
    |  5|   B|   D|2020-01-01| 10|
    |  6|   B|   D|2020-01-01| 10|
    +---+----+----+----------+---+
```

Now I would like to map using **map1** and **map2** column such that ... shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

note that for all different map1 values , **(A,B)** the var values are same **(6,10)** and map1 **can not be null** but map2 can be **null**.

I want to do this without using **join/rdd/udf** as much as possible, just depends on pure pyspark functions for the performance.

first, I create a column dictionary key : value

```
df = df.withColumn("mapp", create_map('map1', 'var'))
```

[image]

I tried using something like but this obviously does not work dynamically.

```
df = df.withColumn('var_mapped',  df["mapp"].getItem(df['map1']))
```

what are some solutions/functions to use in this case? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what spark version you are using?

Comment: I am using spark 3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get all the key-value combinations of map across rows, you can use window functions. In this case, you can use `collect_set` of `struct` of column *map1* and *var* over an all-rows window, then create a map using `map_from_entries`. It would be something like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import map_from_entries, collect_set, struct, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn("mapp", map_from_entries(collect_set(struct(col('map1'), col('var'))).over(Window.partitionBy())))
df.show()

+---+----+----+----------+---+-----------------+
| id|map1|map2|      date|var|             mapp|
+---+----+----+----------+---+-----------------+
|  1|   A|   B|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|
|  2|   A|   B|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|
|  3|   A|   C|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|
|  4|   A|   C|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|
|  5|   B|   D|2020-01-01| 10|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|
|  6|   B|   D|2020-01-01| 10|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|
+---+----+----+----------+---+-----------------+
```

After that, you can map column *map2* using `.getItem()`.

```
df = df.withColumn('res', col('mapp').getItem(col('map2'))).fillna(0)
df.show()

+---+----+----+----------+---+-----------------+---+
| id|map1|map2|      date|var|             mapp|res|
+---+----+----+----------+---+-----------------+---+
|  1|   A|   B|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]| 10|
|  2|   A|   B|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]| 10|
|  3|   A|   C|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|  0|
|  4|   A|   C|2020-01-01|  6|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|  0|
|  5|   B|   D|2020-01-01| 10|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|  0|
|  6|   B|   D|2020-01-01| 10|[B -> 10, A -> 6]|  0|
+---+----+----+----------+---+-----------------+---+
```

Comment: Thank you! is this map_from_entries and getItem strategy faster than join and rdd? if we have big data that is.

Comment: If the map is small enough, I think using broadcast join will be faster